# Bootstrap selection disappears in select box after clicking. Only visible on mouse hover

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have several select boxes on a page. The only problem is that after a value is selected, it becomes blank. I can only see it if I hover my mouse over the box.

This is before clicking:

[image: Before Clicking]

This is after clicking the dropdown

[image: After clicking dropdown]

Here I have chosen 'Bachelors' and it's visible

[image: After choosing]

When I click away anywhere on the screen, it disappears!

[image: After clicking away it disappears]

On mouse hover, it reappears!
[image: Reappears on mouse hover]

Here is my div for the select box:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Degree</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></i></span>
                    <select name="degreeselect" class="form-control selectpicker">
                        <option value=" " selected disabled>Select Degree</option>
                        <option>Bachelors</option>
                        <option>Masters</option>
                        <option>Doctorate</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I honestly don't know what is causing this.

Comment: The problem is most likely linked to any CSS or Javascript code on your page. Can you please provide the CSS/JS related to this?

Comment: It might be the OS. I've had problems like this (text disappearing, etc) on Ubuntu before.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: I could see that from the pictures.

Comment: I haven't changed any CSS, there is something I'm missing here. If I change the button style to btn-primary, the text is visible after clicking away. I'm trying to find where the text is white, but I don't know what the attribute name would be. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note to self: **Pay attention to your modifications in CSS!**

My stylesheet was taken from another page where I had a Bootstrap navbar with a dropdown button. I customized it where the background color was blue, and the text was white.

I inspected the page in my browser and found this:

```
.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Something so small caused such a huge headache, but I figured it out!